# How to config rocketmq in spring-cloud-stream 3.2.2？

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, rocketmq

The documentation on spring.io only have kafka and rabbitMQ,
The demo on github(spring-cloud-alibaba-example) only have old version,
How to  config rocketMQ in spring-cloud-stream-3.2.2 or spring-cloud-alibaba-2021.0.1.0?

Comment: You should probably as this question from alibaba guys as Spring team are not the maintainers of it. Also, your question is extremely general, most likely due to not being able to find documentation - https://spring-cloud-alibaba-group.github.io/github-pages/greenwich/spring-cloud-alibaba.html

Comment: because alibaba have not provide documentation to config with new version of spring-cloud-stream, i had check lot of blog,almost all of plan have flaw,guess config method from spring-cloud-stream+kafka/rabbitMQ by author of blog,so i don't konw how to config correct and want to get documentation by authority.